# Why is my cursor not stopping in the last table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is the cursor:

```
  Declare   @CMD VARCHAR(MAX),
            @CMD1  VARCHAR(MAX),
            @CMD2  VARCHAR(MAX),
            @MSG VARCHAR(MAX),
            @TABELA VARCHAR(100),
            @NOME_TABELA VARCHAR(100),
            @NOME_COLUNA VARCHAR(100),
            @TIPO_DADOS VARCHAR(100),
            @LARGURA INT,
            @PRECISAO INT,
            @ESCALA INT,
            @ANULAVEL CHAR(1),
            @ORDEM_COLUNA INT

DECLARE C_TABELAS CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT NAME
        FROM SYSOBJECTS A
        WHERE TYPE = 'U' 
        ORDER BY 1
DECLARE C_NOMES_TABELAS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NOME_TABELA 
    FROM NOMES_TABELAS 
    ORDER BY NOME_TABELA    

DECLARE C_DETALHES CURSOR FOR 
SELECT NOME_TABELA,NOME_COLUNA,TIPO_DADOS,LARGURA,PRECISAO,ESCALA,ANULAVEL,ORDEM_COLUNA 
FROM COLUNAS_TABELAS 
ORDER BY NOME_TABELA    

  BEGIN
  SET @CMD = ''

  SET @CMD = 'DELETE FROM NOMES_TABELAS';
  EXECUTE (@CMD)
  print @CMD

  SET @CMD = 'DELETE FROM COLUNAS_TABELAS';
 EXECUTE (@CMD)
  print @CMD


  OPEN C_TABELAS   
  FETCH NEXT FROM C_TABELAS INTO @TABELA

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
      EXECUTE GERA_DICIONARIO_TABELA @TABELA,@CMD1 output ,@CMD2 output

      print @CMD1
      print @CMD2
      EXECUTE (@CMD1)
      EXECUTE (@CMD2)

      FETCH NEXT FROM C_TABELAS INTO @TABELA
    END  

  CLOSE C_TABELAS   
  DEALLOCATE C_TABELAS

  ------------------------------------------------------------------
  OPEN C_NOMES_TABELAS   
  FETCH NEXT FROM C_NOMES_TABELAS INTO @TABELA

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
      SET @CMD1 = 'INSERT INTO NOMES_TABELAS (NOME_TABELA,OFICIAL) VALUES (' + '''' + @TABELA + '''' + ',1)' 
      print @CMD1
      FETCH NEXT FROM C_NOMES_TABELAS INTO @TABELA
    END  

  CLOSE C_NOMES_TABELAS   

  -------------------------------------------------------------------

  OPEN C_DETALHES
  FETCH NEXT FROM C_DETALHES INTO @NOME_TABELA,@NOME_COLUNA,@TIPO_DADOS,@LARGURA,
                                  @PRECISAO ,@ESCALA,@ANULAVEL,@ORDEM_COLUNA 

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
      SET @CMD1 = 'INSERT INTO COLUNAS_TABELAS (NOME_TABELA,NOME_COLUNA,TIPO_DADOS,LARGURA,PRECISAO,ESCALA,ANULAVEL,ORDEM_COLUNA) VALUES (' 
      SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 + '''' + @NOME_TABELA + '''' + ','
      SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 + '''' + @NOME_COLUNA + '''' + ','
      SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 + '''' + @TIPO_DADOS + '''' + ','
      IF (@LARGURA IS NOT NULL)  SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 +         @LARGURA + ',' ELSE SET @CMD1= @CMD1 + 'NULL' + ','
      IF (@PRECISAO IS NOT NULL) SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 +         @PRECISAO + ',' ELSE SET @CMD1= @CMD1 + 'NULL' + ',' 
      IF (@ESCALA IS NOT NULL) SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 +         @ESCALA + ',' ELSE SET @CMD1= @CMD1 + 'NULL' + ',' 
      SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 + '''' + @ANULAVEL + '''' + ','
      SET @CMD1 = @CMD1 +  @ORDEM_COLUNA  + ');'
      print @CMD1

      FETCH NEXT FROM C_DETALHES INTO @NOME_TABELA,@NOME_COLUNA,@TIPO_DADOS,@LARGURA,
                                  @PRECISAO ,@ESCALA,@ANULAVEL,@ORDEM_COLUNA 
    END  

  CLOSE C_DETALHES   
  DEALLOCATE C_DETALHES
  DEALLOCATE C_NOMES_TABELAS
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
   end
```

It does what it needs to do, it loops through 2 tables and populate it with some data. OK. But when it reaches the last table, it gives me an error, trying to insert the first table's data again:

```
...
INSERT INTO NOMES_TABELAS (NOME_TABELA,OFICIAL) VALUES ('TRANSACOES_TMP',1)
INSERT INTO NOMES_TABELAS (NOME_TABELA,OFICIAL) VALUES ('USUARIO_SISTEMA',1)
INSERT INTO NOMES_TABELAS (NOME_TABELA,OFICIAL) VALUES 
('VALOR_ACP_CONTRAC_PAIS',1)

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GERA_RELEASE, Line 88
FAIL TO CONVERT THE VARCHAR VALUE  'INSERT INTO COLUNAS_TABELAS (NOME_TABELA,NOME_COLUNA,TIPO_DADOS,LARGURA,PRECISAO,ESCALA,ANULAVEL,ORDEM_COLUNA) VALUES ('ARQUIVO_CLIENTE','ARQUIVO_COMPLETO','CHAR',' to data type int.
```

this `ARQUIVO_CLIENTE` table was already inserted. why is the cursor not stopping in the last table? Should I deallocate it earlier?

If I print `@@FETCH_STATUS`, I can see the last -1, but there's no result.

Comment: Funny part is: When I comment every execute, and only print the commands, it stops in the last table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error gives me a clue as to what might be happening.

`FAIL TO CONVERT THE VARCHAR VALUE... to data type int.`

You have several integer variables that you are trying to concatenate to the @CMD string variable

`@CMD1 +         @LARGURA`

Try using `Cast` or `Convert` against your integer variables before trying to concatenate them with the @CMD string varible.

Comment: Nice, I declared them as varchar. I should have thought about it haha. thanks